# Add jwt token to Google nextauthjs

Tags: session, next.js, jwt, token, next-auth

I'm adding authentication to my nextjs app.
First i add the credentials part with jwt.
When i log using the nextauth's default signin button, i find the accessToken in the console.log of my session.user.

Problem is now i added GoogleProvider, and I have no accessToken, I think problem is in my api/login/route, but i didn't find a way to fix it. Can you help me?

**My provider**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

const handler = NextAuth({
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
      name: "Credentials",
      // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
      // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/login', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: credentials?.username,
                password: credentials?.password,
            }),
        });

        const user = await res.json();
  
        if (user) {
          // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
          return user
        } else {
          // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
          return null
  
          // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
        }
      }
    }),

    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
    }),
],

callbacks: {
  async jwt({token, user}) {
    return({...token, ...user});
  },

  async session({session, token}) {
    session.user = token as any;
    return session;
  }
}
});

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

**Api/login/route**

```
import { signJwtAccessToken } from "@/lib/jwt";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

interface RequestBody {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
export async function POST(request:Request) {
const body:RequestBody = await request.json();
const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
    where:{
        email:body.username,
    }
})

if(user && ( await bcrypt.compare(body.password, user.password))) {
    const {password, ...userWithoutPass} = user;
    const accessToken = signJwtAccessToken(userWithoutPass);
    const result = {
        ...userWithoutPass,
        accessToken,
    }
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(result));
} else return new Response(JSON.stringify(null));
}
```